# Can I pursue an MA and MBA simultaneously?

Tags: masters, degree, distance-learning

I am pursuing a masters degree in Economics (correspondence). I also want to enroll in a MBA program (correspondence). Am I allowed to do that?

Comment: Same school or two different schools?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the education system of the country in which you are studying; besides to the universities you are going to apply.

Some countries do not allow the university students to study two majors during their higher education period. Despite the case that the student is top student or qualified as a student with outstanding academic activities. For instance, some students who are ranked first or second among similar majoring students, have the chance to study in two majors.

Even if there is no restriction, some universities do not allow their students to study two majors simultaneously because they afraid this affect their progress.

Despite the things mentioned about regulations, it may be allowed but be restricted and students may only have the chance to choose their second major very similar to the first one. I mean, the engineering student may not be allowed to choose law as his second major. Or the chemical Engineering student can only apply for a BSc in chemistry sciences.

Some universities encourage masters students to study in MBA alongside their own major; specially the engineering students as they become familiar with some non-engineering topics and be prepared to accept management roles in their future careers.

In your case, I have to say these things:

1. You need to ask the university in which you are studying in whether they allow you to study a second major simultaneously.
2. You need to asses your own ability if you are prepared enough to study a second masters or not. Because an MA in economics has its difficulties and this will get worth when you start your research and thesis. Sometimes, studying a second major will not either help you improve your knowledge and do a better research; or even because of lots of courses and lack of time; you may lose your way for the first major.
3. You may need to consult your supervisor if he allows you or encourages you to do so besides your masters research thesis.
4. If you have to pay for MBA, you also need to think about how to pay the fees or find a good fund or scholarship.

If you are not sure about those difficulties, I encourage you to finish your first MA, work for two or three years and then apply for a MBA. I know some good business schools that require the students some job experience before assessing their applications. This way, you may gain most of your academic studies.